# Why can't this class deduce the final template type from the constructor argument passed in?

Tags: c++, templates

I always have trouble knowing when the compiler in C++ can deduce a template argument from a constructor argument, and I know there's a difference between functions and classes in what is deduced. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
template <uint64 dst_texel_size_, uint64 src_texel_size_, uint64 tile_num_texels_x_, uint64 tile_num_texels_y_, uint64 num_tiles_x_, uint64 num_tiles_y_,
typename src_to_dst_function_t>
class ImageStitcher
{public:
    ImageStitcher(src_to_dst_function_t src_to_dst_function) : src_to_dst_function_t(src_to_dst_function_t) { }
    src_to_dst_function_t src_to_dst_function;
    };
```

And then construct it like this:

```
int main()
{
constexpr uint64 num_tiles_x = 2;
    constexpr uint64 num_tiles_y = 2;
    constexpr uint32 num_tiles_to_stitch = 4;

    ImageStitcher<1, sizeof(float), 3600, 3600, num_tiles_x, num_tiles_y> image_stitcher([](unsigned char* src_texel, unsigned char* dst_texel)
        {                                                        //   ^^^ not providing the type here


        });

return 0;
}
```

I'm not providing the type in the template argument list, but the constructor, why doesn't it deduce it? Can the last template argument be deduce in functions but not classes? What should I do in this case?

Comment: CTAD is all or nothing. You need to provide no template arguments whatsoever for it to work.

Comment: you're explicitly saying that there is a template argument in the list and then you're not sending the last argument as if it was never there. Thats not how template arguments works. You have to either send 0 arguments, or send all arguments, not send the arguments and leave them halfway

Comment: @ShreeyashShrestha But with functions templates you don't have to do all or nothing right?

Comment: template arguments dont see the arguments as functions or variables. Theyre just values.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround could be to seperate the template parameters via a factory class. Some template parameters are parameters of the factory class and the template parameter to be deduced is the only template parameter of the factory class' static factory method. So instead of invoking a constructor directly, you call the factory method like so:

```cpp
int main()
{
    constexpr uint64_t num_tiles_x = 2;
    constexpr uint64_t num_tiles_y = 2;
    constexpr uint32_t num_tiles_to_stitch = 4;

    ImageStitcherFactory<1, sizeof(float), 3600, 3600, num_tiles_x, num_tiles_y>::create(
        [](unsigned char* src_texel, unsigned char* dst_texel)
        {
            //   ^^^ not providing the type here
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Code on Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qjqKjKefd)